# Access tuple inside RDD pyspark

Tags: pyspark

**Input:**

```
('MechanicalKeyboards', 2, 'ForgetfulDoryFish')
('MechanicalKeyboards', 1, 'cheshire26')
('MechanicalKeyboards', 1, 'Sygaldry')
('scala', 5, 'hyperforce')
('xkcd', 3, 'brinjal66')
('MechanicalKeyboards', 1, 'Sygaldry')
('MechanicalKeyboards', 1, 'DzyDzyDino')
```

This is my RDD.

With-e = `lines.filter(lambda x: 'e' in lines[0])`

**Desired Output:**

```
('MechanicalKeyboards', 2, 'ForgetfulDoryFish')
('MechanicalKeyboards', 1, 'cheshire26')
('MechanicalKeyboards', 1, 'Sygaldry')
('MechanicalKeyboards', 1, 'Sygaldry')
('MechanicalKeyboards', 1, 'DzyDzyDino')
```

I'm trying to filter the out all the elements which doesn't contains 'e' in the first element of the RDD tuple, Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do like below

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([
...     ('MechanicalKeyboards', 2, 'ForgetfulDoryFish'),
...     ('MechanicalKeyboards', 1, 'cheshire26'),
...     ('MechanicalKeyboards', 1, 'Sygaldry'),
...     ('scala', 5, 'hyperforce'),
...     ('xkcd', 3, 'brinjal66'),
...     ('MechanicalKeyboards', 1, 'Sygaldry'),
...     ('MechanicalKeyboards', 1, 'DzyDzyDino')
...     ])
>>> 
>>> rdd.filter(lambda x: True if 'e' in x[0] else False).collect()
[('MechanicalKeyboards', 2, 'ForgetfulDoryFish'), ('MechanicalKeyboards', 1, 'cheshire26'), ('MechanicalKeyboards', 1, 'Sygaldry'),     ('MechanicalKeyboards', 1, 'Sygaldry'), ('MechanicalKeyboards', 1, 'DzyDzyDino')]
```